# multi form - form tag in foreach

Tags: spring-mvc, foreach, jstl

In Spring MVC, I want to create multi form in same page. According to me, ıt is logically true. But it gives error as

> ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.HiddenInputTag -
>   Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'cost'
>   available as request attribute

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = {  "/vehicle_cost" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String vehicleCost(Model model, @RequestParam(defaultValue="0") int vId) {
    List<CostModel> _costs = null;
    List<CurrencyModel> _currencies = accountingService.getCurrencyList();
    List<IdElemModel> _cost_per_types = accountingService.getCostPerTypeList();
    if(vId > 0){
        _costs = operationService.getVehicleCostsByVehicleId(vId);
    }
    else{

    }
    model.addAttribute("costs", _costs);
    model.addAttribute("currencies",_currencies);
    model.addAttribute("cost_per_types",_cost_per_types);
    return "vehicle_management/vehicle_cost";
}
```

View

```
<c:forEach items="${costs}" var="cost">
                    <form:form commandName="cost" method="POST"  action="save_vehicle_cost" cssClass="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <form:hidden path="costId" />
                    <form:hidden path="costCategoryId" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <form:input path="cost" cssClass="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                            <form:input path="taxRatio" cssClass="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <form:select path="currencyId"  cssClass="form-control">
                            <option value="-1">Currency</option>
                                <form:options items="${currencies}" itemLabel="currency"
                                    itemValue="currencyId" />
                                    <form:options/>
                            </form:select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <form:select path="costPerTypeId"  cssClass="form-control">
                            <option value="-1">Per Type</option>
                                <form:options items="${cost_per_types}" itemLabel="elem"
                                    itemValue="id" />
                                <form:options/>
                            </form:select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <form:input path="periodBegin" cssClass="form-control dateInput" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <form:input path="periodEnd" cssClass="form-control dateInput" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">SAVE</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </form:form>
                </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form is expecting "cost" to be in the request, but your loop is not putting the object in the correct scope. Following standard Spring MVC pattern to prepopulating command objects in the controller, you can just preload them:

In your controller put each cost object into the correct scope, by loading them with a key like "cost_" + id:

```
for(CostModel c: _costs) {
    model.addAttribute("cost_" + c.getId(), c);
}
```

In your jsp when you render the form, look for a "cost_${id}" in the request scope:

```
<c:forEach items="${costs}" var="cost">
    <form:form commandName="cost_${cost.id}" method="POST"  action="save_vehicle_cost" cssClass="form-horizontal" role="form">
    ...
...
</c:forEach>
```

I hope that helps.